# Jquery:- listview not refreshing

Tags: jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile

**Problem:-**

Here my problem is that when I am assigning `$('#ulmember').attr( 'data-filter','true');`. Even I am not getting `search-bar` in my `listview`.Even when I am displaying `listview data-filter` property in alert then I am getting `true`.Even this attribute not applying
on `listview`.And This attribute I am applying on `memsearch click`.I want to assign `data-role="true"` by jquery code. so if somebody have any idea about my problem so please help me.

My Example is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mXjHJ/1350/)

**source code:-**

```
<div data-role="header">
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="right" >
        <ul>
            <li><a id="memsearch"  href="#" data-icon="search" style="padding:0px"><h2 id="groupname" style="margin:8px">Member List</h2></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="memberlist">        
    <ul id="ulmember" data-role="listview" data-filter-placeholder="Search Member..." data-inset="true">
        <li><a id="mem1"><h2>Member 1</h2></a></li>
        <li><a id="mem2"><h2>Member 2</h2></a></li>
        <li><a id="mem3"><h2>Member 3</h2></a></li>
        <li><a id="mem4"><h2>Member 4</h2></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery Code :-**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#memsearch").click(function(){

       alert($("#ulmember").attr("data-filter"));

        $('#ulmember').attr( 'data-filter','true');

        alert($("#ulmember").attr("data-filter"));
        $("#ulmember").listview('refresh');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working as expected. Do it this way:

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn toggle">Show/Hide Filter</a>
    </div>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter-placeholder="Search Member..." data-inset="true" id="ulmember">
        <li><a href="#">Member 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Member 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Member 3</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Member 4</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Member 5</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Member 6</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#ulmember").filterable({
    filterReveal: false
});
$(".ui-filterable").addClass("ui-screen-hidden");
$(".toggle").on("click", function () {
    $(".ui-filterable").toggleClass("ui-screen-hidden");
    $("ul li").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
    $("#ulmember").listview("refresh");
});
```

You can check it on: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q65cb/6/)